# In a two equation system, what is the meaning of the assumption "exogenous X is uncorrelated with ε1ε2"

Tags: regression, econometrics, covariance, endogeneity

Assume a triangular system such as

\begin{eqnarray*}
Y = X'\beta_1 + D\gamma_1 + \varepsilon_1 \\
D = X'\beta_2 + \varepsilon_2
\end{eqnarray*}

with $Y$ and $D$ as observed endogenous variables, $X$ a vector of observed exogenous variables, and $\varepsilon_j$ as the unobserved error terms.

What is the meaning of this assumption $Cov(X, \varepsilon_1\varepsilon_2)=0$? When is it violated?

Comment: What is the assumed relation between the two error terms?

Comment: ε1 and ε2 may be correlated and there is some heteroscedasticity in the form of $cov(X, e_2^2) != 0$ but I can't get my head around when the assumption is satisfied or violated.

Answer (score 1):

This must be a [strict exogeneity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares#Classical_linear_regression_model) from classical OLS model. There's also a weak exogeneity, which is more realistic.

It's violated when your errors are correlated with regressors. It's a very common issue in econometrics, see the discussion [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endogeneity_%28econometrics%29).

Comment: Are you sure about that? The context also states that the exogeneity assumption E(εX)=0 holds and the assumption refers to the term ε1ε2 not just εj. E(εj|X)=0 would be the standard exogeneity assumption. The text also states that the assumption is automatically satisfied if the "mean zero errors are conditionally independent" ε1 ⊥ ε2|Z = 0

Comment: Actually, this is not OLS, you're right. It's a [linear simultaneous equations model] (https://hec.unil.ch/docs/files/23/100/book_draft_chapters_sem_intro_identification.pdf). The condition though is similar to strict exogeneity.